# How to send slack message to some individual user using Python?

Tags: python, api, slack

I am trying to send individual messages in Slack. I know how to send it to a channel by using its incoming webhook url. But how to do so for some individual user?

Comment: Please let us know what you've already tried so far by showing some of your code, and which parts of the docs you've been looking at so far in search of a solution.

Comment: Found a way - well multiple ways but the most optimum is to set up incoming webhooks for users too

Comment: Questions (and answers) posted to SO should also be useful to other users who come across them. Since yours isn't particularly clear and you didn't update it with a proper answer, I would suggest deleting it.

Comment: Sorry @Kay I will update my answer to reflect the problem and the solution better. I believe it will be helpful too. Just need a bit more time. Hope you understand. Thanks for making us better users of stack overflow!